# mongoDB set name does not match

Tags: mongodb, replication, database

I have got 3 mongod demo replicates servers running on my machine. I have used following command to create replicated server:

```
F:\>mongod --replSet test2 --dbpath 2 --port 27112 --oplogSize 50 --logpath log.2 --logappend
all output going to: log.2
```

Like this I have test1 on 27111 port, test2 on 27112 port and test3 on 27113 port. Yet at configuration I am getting an error:

```
cfg = {
        "_id" : "test1",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "localhost:27111"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "localhost:27112"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "localhost:27113"
                }
        ]
}
> rs.initiate( cfg )
{
        "errmsg" : "couldn't initiate : set name does not match the set name host localhost:27112 expects",
        "ok" : 0
}
```

Now what do I have to do to make it match ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the sets I would run should have the same name.
For an instance if I run

```
mongod --replSet test2 --dbpath 2 --port 27112 --oplogSize 50 --logpath log.2 --logappend
all output going to: log.2
```

Then the other mongo servers I would intend to be in that set, should have the same name `test2`

Answer (score 2):

The name or variable used in  `"cfg" = { "_id":="test1" }`

should confirm with the name used in the following for parameter `replSet` for all the members in that replication set.

Then things will work smoothly for you

```
"start mongod --replSet "test1" --logpath "1.log" --dbpath C:\Replica\rs01 --port 27017 --oplogSize 64
```

Good luck

Rao

Comment: Absolutely. I had a different name in replSet name in docker-compose command and config so had the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The steps below worked for me:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "C:\MongoDB\data01" --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
mongod --port 27018 --dbpath "C:\MongoDB\data02" --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
```

These two lines start two different mongo instances in different ports.
On the second instance, I have added replSet=rs0 in mongod.conf.

Then add the secondary in rs0 node by this command:

```
rs.add("localhost:27018")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the name of your machine or 127.0.0.1. It's a best practice to use the DNS name.

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB replicaset doesn't accept `localhost`. Try using the actual machine name while adding the node to the replicaset as following:

```
rs.add("MY_MACHINE_NAME:27017");
```

Answer (score -1):

When adding the replica sets, the --replset should be same for all three. For example if for primary it was "rs01", it should be same for other two also .